How to dereference an object pointer?
Currently I have a student class and a roster class. The roster class is holding an array of pointers that point towards objects of the student class.
student* RosterArray[20];

cR.RosterArray[0] = &stud1;
cR.RosterArray[1] = &stud2; 
cR.RosterArray[2] = &stud3;
cR.RosterArray[3] = &stud4;
cR.RosterArray[4] = &stud5;

Is there a way that I can dereference the pointers to somehow show values from each of the student class objects?
I tried the obvious method of doing it, which is
cR.*RosterArray[i]; 

which didn't work.

.* is a syntax for member pointers. You just need to use dereference operator on the pointer object that you get back from the array.

Also we need a [mcve]

"which didn't work..." Always post complete error along with your question and a [mcve]

*(cR.RosterArray[n]) or simply cR.RosterArray[n]->member

A side note: in C++ it is recommended to use std::array (for fixed size) or std::vector (for dynamic size) instead of C arrays, and smart pointers instead of raw ones.

There is no difference between cR.RosterArray[i] and any other student*.

Try *(cr.RosterArray[i])   or (if student is a class/struct type) access members using cr.RosterArray[i]->member (equivalently (*(cr.RosterArray[i])).member).  cR.*RosterArray[i] is accessing a pointer-to-member and (in cases - different to yours - where it is syntactically valid, because RosterArray is a pointer-to-member unlike your code where it is an array of pointers) would be equivalent to (cR.*RosterArray)[i].

This expression:
cR.*RosterArray[i]

Attempts to derefernce a pointer to member RosterArray with the object cR.
But it is not what you have in your case.
Rather cR is an objects that contains an array called RosterArray, which containers pointers you want to dereference.
The expression cR.RosterArray[i] is a pointer, and therefore to dereference it you need to apply operator* over this whole expression:
*(cR.RosterArray[i])

If you want to access a member of the object pointed by the pointer, you can also use:
(cR.RosterArray[i])-> ...

Where ... is a name of a member of that object.
A side note:
It is recommeded to use std::array over a C style array (or std::vector if you need a dynamic size array).

.* is a member access operator and is used in expressions through pointers to members.
Here you just need to use dereference operator on the pointer object that you get back from the array as shown below:
*(cR.RosterArray[n]) //this works


Also, std::array can be used here instead of c-style array.
What are the advantages of using std::array over C-style arrays?

Is there a way to use cout in conjunction with this?
I'm doing cout << *(cR.RosterArray[0])  << endl; but this doesn't compile.

@droid Yes, but for your follow up question kindly ask a new separate question. And in your new separate question kindly provide a [mcve]. Since these problems are different, asking a new separate question is recommended.
